# Delete without reload page with Codeigniter(3)

Tags: codeigniter

there was a problem with deleting data without reloading the page.

I bring to your attention my view:

```
    echo
'<table id="" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" > 
<tr>
<td >Text 1</td>
<td>Text 2</td>
<td>
<a href="' . base_url() . 'tournaments/tournaments_participant_delete/' . $id_tournament . '/' . $id_participant . '/' . $id_category . '" id="delete_participant_tournament" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
</tr>
</table>
<br>';
```

I bring to your attention my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete_participant_tournament").click(function(event){
        var href = $(this).attr("href")
        var btn = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: href,
            success: function(response) {

                if (response == "Success")
                {
                    $(btn).closest('tr').fadeOut("slow");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and of course my controller

```
public
function tournaments_participant_delete($tournament_id,$participant_id, $category)
{
    $this->tournaments_model->tournament_categories_participants_delete($tournament_id, $participant_id, $category);
    redirect('tournaments/add_participant_tournament/'.$tournament_id, 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well very first thing what i noticed you can remove is

```
type="submit"
```

Other thing that was noticed, you are making AJAX call. Then why in the controller you wana do a redirect for the same?

```
redirect('tournaments/add_participant_tournament/'.$tournament_id, 'refresh');
```

You should rather return response like

```
echo "Success" or echo "Error" // Whatever be the state
```

Change it and it should work as desired.

Comment: well, i have noticed such situation / errors. Can you double check on something by viewing the page source, by any chance do you have more then one jquery being called up for? There are times in my past, me too had this problem when there were more then one jquery being requested. If that is the case, will like you to remove one of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Try spending some time to understand AJAX**

**[HERE](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/simple-ajax-post-example-with-php-codeIgniter-framework-and-jquery) is one of the example, Codeigniter with jQuery AJAX.**

In your code avoid redirect from server side after completing the logic.
ie. instead of this

```
redirect('tournaments/add_participant_tournament/'.$tournament_id, 'refresh');
```

you can simply pass the data whatever you want for the view and retrieve it in success function of Jquery AJAX

```
success: function(response) {
     // Here you can get the data passed by server
}
```

Happy Coding...